# Python を使って複数のバッチファイルを一度に実行したい

Tags: python

pythonを使用して複数のバッチファイルを一度に実行したいと考えております。
やり方について記事を調べたのですが、見つかりませんでした。
ご教授いただけましたら幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 何故Pythonなのでしょう？ バッチファイルだけでも START コマンドで終了を待たずに次のバッチファイルが実行できますが。[start（バッチファイルやサブルーチンの呼び出し）](https://jj-blues.com/cms/command-start/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。特にpythonでなければいけない理由はありません。この場合はコマンドプロンプトでstartを用いるという理解でよろしいですか？

Comment: そうです。さらにバッチファイルの中で使うことも出来ます。

Answer (score 1):

ちなみに本当にPythonでやりたい場合は、[subprocess.Popen()](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)で、creationflagsパラメータに[subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE) を指定して実行ですね。

こちらはUnix系の記事
[subprocess.Popenからシェルを実行する](https://nansystem.com/python-call-vs-check-out-vs-run-vs-popen/#subprocess-popen%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A7%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

Windowsバッチの記事(英語の元記事と翻訳と)
[Python: How can I execute bat file in new cmd window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13525129/9014308) / [Python：新しいcmdウィンドウでbatファイルを実行するにはどうすればいいですか？](https://codeday.me/jp/qa/20190601/911350.html)